# Node-Webkit Ctrl-plus and Ctrl-minus

Tags: node-webkit, shortcut

How do i make node-webkit (NW) accept <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> as shortcuts?
I have tried:

```
Ctrl++
Ctrl+Plus
Ctrl+Plus
Ctrl+Minus
Ctrl+-
Ctrl+minus
```

but it doesn't work. Every time it gives me a fail message.

Here is my current code:

```
var option = {
  key : "Ctrl+plus",
  active : function() {
    console.log("Global desktop keyboard shortcut: " + this.key + " active."); 
  },
  failed : function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
   }
    };enter code here

    var shortcut = new nw.Shortcut(option);

    nw.App.registerGlobalHotKey(shortcut);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  had to do something similar and ended up using JS:

```
$(window).keypress(function(event) {
    if (!(event.which == 61)) return true;
    # 61 is ctrl + plus on Mac, probably different on windows 
    alert("Ctrl-plus pressed");
    event.preventDefault();
    return false; 
});
```